# Multiple Gateway, for VPN and Internet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing

I'm pretty new as a system administrator and I've got a problem to deal with in my company.

We recently got a VPN and it is working great, I already tested it and all is good. Now in my main site, the VPN gateway is `192.168.2.254` but it doesn't provide Internet; for that, I got a router with an IP of `192.168.0.1` which is casting to another router at `192.168.0.99`. (Don't know why it is configured this way; my ISP installed it that way.) Additionally, I'm using Windows Server 2003 with AD for all users.

How can I get all users to have both VPN access and Internet access? Should I cascade the VPN router and use forwarding? Should I add routes to the Windows server? If so, how? (I already tried some routes.)

At the moment, all I can configure it to is users having access to Internet *OR* to the VPN. Not being able to have both working together.

I've been working on this issue for some time now but still no success.

Tried

```
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 metric 1 if 10
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.254 metric 1 if 10
```

with this I was able to have both networks but they don't work at the same time. I got Internet or I got the intranet. Never both.

I tried to draw a network diagram but I can't post images here yet.

```
VPN router 192.168.1.254 ------- switches ------- Server 192.168.0.150
NET router   192.168.0.1 -------/   |
                                    |
                             PC's 192.168.0.xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, i finally got it:

route -p add 192.168.2.0 mask 255.255.255 192.168.1.254

It was actually very simple :/

Route says that my all conections to 192.168.2.0 (Main site IP) will use gateway 192.168.1.254(VPN router IP) All NIC's in the network still have the default gateway 192.168.0.1 which is my internet router but when any conection try to go to 192.168.2.0 it will route to my VPN router 192.168.1.254.